# How to get user group name by providing user id

Tags: joomla2.5

I am using joomla 2.5.

I want to get **user group name by providing user id.** is there any core function to achieve this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following function to get the user group titles for a given user Id.

```
        function getGroupTitles($id)
        {
            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);
            $query
            ->select('title')->from('#__usergroups')
            ->where('id IN (' . implode(',', array_values(JFactory::getUser($id)->groups)) . ')');
            $db->setQuery($query);
            return $db->loadColumn();
        }
```

Example: print_r(getGroupTitles(427)); 
will output an array similar to this:
Array ( [0] => Registered [1] => Author )

Answer (score 0):

You can find the user group name  by the following custom function.

```
function getUserGroups($gid)
    {
        // Initialise variables.
        $db     = JFactory::getDBO();
        $query  = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->select('a.title AS text')
            ->from('#__usergroups AS a')
            ->where('a.id='.$gid)
            ->group('a.id')
            ->order('a.lft ASC');

        $db->setQuery($query);
        $options = $db->loadObjectList();

        return $options;
    }
```

Just call this function and pass the `groups` in the function for example

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser(48);
$usergroupname = getUserGroups($user->groups[8]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will help you.

If you need to pass the value through function params means, you can alter the code.I have list the query and the result.

```
<?php

    $user = JFactory::getUser();

    $db     = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query  = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select('s.title AS group_name');
    $query->from('#__user_usergroup_map AS c');
    $query->join('LEFT', '#__usergroups AS s ON s.id = c.group_id' );
    $query->where('c.user_id = '.$user->id);
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $group_name = $db->loadResult();

    echo $group_name;
?>
```

Comment: this almost works -- but only echo's the first group, not all of them